# Android Google Play Game Services startQuickGame, undefined makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder()

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've been searching around for hours now and I can't find the answer somewhere on the internet... hope you guys can help me out.

I want to implement a quick game over Google Play Game Services:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

I followed the instructions on the google site. A Login with a google Account inside of my app was successfull. Now i wanted to implement a Quick Game, but there is an error message on:

```
makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
```

The Method makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder(); is undefined for the type GameActivity

Here's some of my code:

```
import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomConfig;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;


public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private static InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private AdView adView;
    private int FieldWidth;
    private int FieldHeight;
    private EditText playerEdit;
    private Button settingsSave;
    private GameView theGameView;
    private static SoundPool soundPool;
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundsMap;
    IInAppBillingService mService;
    private Sql2Player SqlArray2Player; 
    private Sql3Player SqlArray3Player; 
    private SqlQPlayer SqlArrayQPlayer; 
    public ConnectivityManager conMgr;
    public GameLoopThread theGameLoopThread;

    private void startQuickGame() {
        // auto-match criteria to invite one random automatch opponent.  
        // You can also specify more opponents (up to 3). 
        Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);

        // build the room config:
        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
        RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();

        // create room:
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);

    }

....
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This from https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting:

> Listeners not called
>
> Missing multiplayer listeners
>
> Multiplayer games typically need to set up listeners such as RoomUpdateListener, RoomStatusUpdateListener and RealTimeMessageReceivedListener.
>
> A common mistake when using this listeners is forgetting to add them to the RoomConfig object on all code paths that set up a multiplayer game.
>
> We recommend that you write a helper method that creates a RoomConfig.Builder with the appropriate callbacks:

```
private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    RoomConfig.Builder builder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    builder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    builder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);

    // ...add other listeners as needed...

    return builder;
}
```

> Then, use this method every time you set up a multiplayer game instead of setting up the callbacks manually. You must do this on all scenarios where you start a multiplayer game, regardless of whether you are creating or joining a room."

I suspect your code is just missing one or more of the listeners. I did not write a helper method in my app. Instead, I suggest you look at the ButtonClicker sample where you will see a simpler approach:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/eclipse_compat/ButtonClicker